# C#.NET Application throwing ODBC Driver Mismatch Error when running on 64-bit environment

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2012, odbc

All,
I inherited a C#.Net project that I'm working on making some updates to. Everything seems to work fine on my local workstation using Visual Studio Professional 2012, Windows 7 - 32 bit (I know..).

When I push it up to my test server(Windows 7, 64 Bit), when the app tries to connect to the Databases using the ODBC, I receive the following error: " driver manager the specified dsn contains an architecture mismatch between the driver and application" error.

This app had previously worked on 64 bit machines (Windows Server), and I have not changed any of the ODBC code. In addition, the ODBC connections on the 64 bit machine exist in the 32-bit ODBC connection manager.

I'm using the System.Data.ODBC.ODBCConnection class with the application targeting the .NET Framework 4.

Any ideas on next steps to resolve this? As far as I can tell the Class I'm using has currently worked on 64-bit systems as long as the 32-bit ODBC connection existed.

Code I'm using is below (its hitting the exception line and thats where I'm getting the message):

```
        string sConnection = "";
        OdbcConnection conn;

        sConnection = "DSN=" + sDSN + ";uid=" + _User + ";pwd=" + _Password;

        try
        {
            conn = new OdbcConnection(sConnection);
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error: Cannot connect to database. Error (" + ex.Message + ")";
        }
```

Comment: What is the Platform Target you're building to? Any CPU/x86/x64?

Comment: Good Catch :). I had it set to "Any CPU" and I think it was misinterpreting it. I just set it it to x86 to match my ODBC SystemDSN  and rebuilt it it seems to be resolved.  I assume its best to just explicitly define your using the 32 bit driver / 32 bit ODBC when installing on a 64 bit system.
Thanks!